# Label recognition with Facebook's library Fasttext

Tags: python, label

Ok so I have been playing with Facebook's newest text classification python library and I'm struggling a bit with label recognition.

If I understood the input have to be lines in a txt file, each line containing both the features and the label. The label can be recognize by the classifier by it's prefix :"__label__".

But fore some reason I'm unnable to get my classifier to recognize my labels when I run a simple test code. Here it is:

```
import fasttext

classifier = fasttext.supervised('toto.txt', 'model')
print classifier.label_prefix
print classifier.labels
raise SystemExit(0)
```

Which give me this result in the log :

```
__label__
[]
```

So the code knows that the prefix is : "__label__" but can't catch them in my input file. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

You need to **show the content of "toto.txt"** in order to get some help.

From what I can see now, there is no problem with the code you provided.

**(btw, make sure your toto.txt is encoded in 'utf-8', otherwise, you need to set an encoding param in classifier)**